# How can I see json code color-formatted within a php file in eclipse?

Tags: php, json, eclipse, editor, formatter

I installed the [json editor plugin](https://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/json-editor-plugin) to my eclipse workspace. The plugin does a good job but I am only able to see the formatting and different colors when I use json language inside a json-file (like xxx.json). I need to put the json code inside a php file so I would like to see the formatting for json-code inside the php-file (like xxx.php).

When I am editing a php-file the editor shows me php, html, css and javascript color-formatted but this is not the case with json. How can I enable this?

Thanks!